# How to use multiple ClientKafka in one service?

Tags: node.js, typescript, apache-kafka, microservices, nestjs

I have a problem with using multiple `ClientKafka` in one service, here is my implementation:

```
@Controller()
export class ApiController implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(
    @Inject("ACCOUNT_SERVICE") private readonly accountKafkaClient: ClientKafka,
    @Inject("WORKSPACE_SERVICE") private readonly workspaceKafkaClient: ClientKafka
  ) { }

  async onModuleInit() {
    const requestPatterns = [
      'topic'
    ];
    requestPatterns.forEach((pattern) => {
      this.accountKafkaClient.subscribeToResponseOf(`account.${pattern}`);
    });
    await this.accountKafkaClient.connect();
  }

  async onModuleDestroy() {
    await this.accountKafkaClient.close();
  }

  @Get()
  async sendMessage() {
    const data = {
      msg: "account.topic"
    }

    const kafkaResponse = this.accountKafkaClient.send<any>('account.topic', JSON.stringify(data));
    const response = await firstValueFrom(kafkaResponse);

    const kafkaResponse2 = this.workspaceKafkaClient.send<any>('workspace.topic', JSON.stringify(response )) //THIS IS NOT RUNNING, WORKSPACE_SERVICE NOT RECEIVE ANY MESSAGE

    return await firstValueFrom(kafkaResponse2);
  }
}
```

can someone tell me why `workspaceKafkaClient` is not sending any message to `WORKSPACE_SERVICE` microservice? I try with passing this client in `onModule...` functions like `accountKafkaClient` but it didn't help me,

here is also my settings in module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ClientsModule.register([
      {
        name: 'ACCOUNT_SERVICE',
        transport: Transport.KAFKA,
        options: {
          client: {
            clientId: 'account_service',
            brokers: ['localhost:29092'],
          },
          consumer: {
            groupId: 'account-consumer',
          },
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'WORKSPACE_SERVICE',
        transport: Transport.KAFKA,
        options: {
          client: {
            clientId: 'workspace_service',
            brokers: ['localhost:29092'],
          },
          consumer: {
            groupId: 'workspace-consumer',
          },
        },
      },
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [ApiController],
  providers: [
    ApiService,
    // KafkaProducerProvider,
  ],
})
export class ApiModule {}
```

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You only need one producer client per application, but Kafka producers never immediately send data to brokers.

You need to flush them for that to happen, which is what `await firstValueFrom(...)` should do, but you've not shown that method.

Otherwise, you seem to be trying to get the reponse from one topic to send to another, which is what a consumer should be used for, rather than blocking on one producer request.

Comment: I'm a little bit change `sendMessage` function, I understand your answer, but what in situations where I need to call two microservices to return value for request to api? A small example is in sendMessage function, ofcourse without big business logic, only main assumption

Comment: In my experience, you should just return HTTP 201-Accepted, or 500 server error if you had some Kafka exception. You shouldn't just return the Kafka sender response to the HTTP response.

Comment: But I'm na talking about exceptions... I'm talking about using multiple kafka clients...

Comment: You're not "calling two services" here, though. Both are producing to the exact same Kafka cluster. You can use one client and simply use different parameters for the topic and payload.

Comment: Also, maybe the "workspace service" consumer simply isn't running. You'd need to debug that separately.